# ApiPlatform : CustomSearchFilter : doctrine generates a sub-request for an andWhere

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I created a CustomSearchFilter in ApiPlatform.

There is only one filter in the query.
For the example, I put only this in the filter :

```
$queryBuilder->leftJoin($rootAlias . ".contracts", "c");
$queryBuilder->leftJoin( "c.payments", "p");
$queryBuilder->andWhere( "p.id = 140");
```

It works fine, but the query generated by doctrine in the profiler is the following.

```
SELECT
  l0_.id AS id_0,
  l0_.company AS company_1,
  l0_.name AS name_2,
  l0_.name2 AS name2_3,
FROM
  landlord l0_
  LEFT JOIN contract l1_ ON l0_.id = l1_.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN payment l2_ ON l1_.id = l2_.contract_id
WHERE
  l0_.id IN (
    SELECT
      l3_.id
    FROM
      landlord l3_
      LEFT JOIN contract l4_ ON l3_.id = l4_.customer_id
      LEFT JOIN payment l5_ ON l4_.id = l5_.contract_id
    WHERE
      l5_.id = 140
  )
ORDER BY
  l0_.id ASC
```

The query generated should be much simpler without subquery.

When I delete one of the two leftJoin or the andWhere, there is no more subquery.

Do you know if I've done something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have other `where`s before this one? If this is the only where you have then you can just use `->where( "p.id = 140")`. You can also stack each function after each other instead of writing `$queryBuilder->something()` on every line.

Comment: One more thing you can do is move the where in the join like so: `$queryBuilder->leftJoin( "c.payments", "p", "WITH", "p.id = 140");`

Comment: I tried with `->where()`and it's the same.
And it works with `$queryBuilder->leftJoin( "c.payments", "p", "WITH", "p.id = 140");` but it's not a where clause.